# A different use of foreign key

Tags: key, constraints

Lets assume there is this table called `STUDENTS`, having columns `StudentNumber` int as primary key, `StudentName nchar(15)`, `StudentAge int`, `StudentDeskmate int`. I have set `StudentDeskmate` as a foreign key referencing `StudentNumber`. What I also want is a deskmate to be at the same age with a student. How can I ensure this?
I tried subqueries, check constraints but none of them worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Show us what you have tried. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: It is my first time here; just trying to adapt myself to the site now, which is not so easy at first. Sorry for the mistakes.